# replace all calls to Assembly.Load with call to my own method

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

I'm reverse engineering some malware made in .Net

I'm trying to automate finding the payload by having a program that will replace all calls to Assembly.Load with a call to my own method (a method that basically dumps the assembly to a file before loading it).

How can I do this? I assume have to use Mono.Cecil, but I haven't been able to find much documentation or tutorials on it.

Edit: I should clarify that the assemblies loaded do not come from dll's but encrypted byte arrays and bitmaps images. The only way to actually get the original assembly is right as they are loaded.

Comment: Really tough malware could go so far as to generate the calls to `Assembly.Load` dynamically, so you can't rewrite it with IL rewriters like Mono.Cecil. The most foolproof way of hooking this is to set a breakpoint on `Assembly.Load` if you're OK with running the code in a debugger (like `windbg`), or (even more difficult) writing a custom profiler that hooks calls to `Assembly.Load`. If you're sure the malware only has direct calls to `Assembly.Load`, those can be rewritten. Another option is a custom CLR host, but I don't know if you can hook loads from byte streams that way.

Comment: it loads and runs assemblies that contain more assemblies that are loaded and run. I think there's about three layers.
The class I want to hook Assembly.Load with would also add itself to loaded assemblies calls to Assembly.Load so it works recursively.
I can't do that with windbg.
I've already reversed it by hand; I'm just trying to automate it for use on some other samples from the same family

Comment: If all your care about is knowing what assemblies are loaded when, you could simply hook up a handler to `AppDomain.AssemblyLoaded`. You will not be able to get the assembly contents as a byte array for dynamically generated assemblies, but you can read (and copy) disk-based assemblies that way, even temporary ones.

Comment: no I need the contents of the assemblies. They're custom libraries written by the malware author so knowing their names wouldn't do anything for me.

Comment: "I can't do that with `windbg`" -- sure you can. No matter how many layers are inbetween, ultimately an assembly load will call an entry point in the unmanaged part of the CLR, regardless of how the assembly load is happening (be it `Assembly.Load` or anything else). Don't ask me what that entry point is called, but a full stack walk of an `Assembly.Load` should find it. You won't be able to run *managed* code when the breakpoint is hit, of course.

Comment: I believe I couldn't because it was creating child processes. someone else used windbg with it to get the first level assembly dumps and told me it wouldn't work for going deeper.

Comment: Child processes *considerably* complicate things. No matter what method you pick, you will *also* have to hook the child process creation to apply it recursively. At this point, your most worthwhile avenue sounds like using the CLR profiler interfaces -- by setting `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` and `COR_PROFILER` in the environment globally, you can profile all managed code as it's run. This is assuming the malware doesn't override the environment blocks of its children. Working around that is possible, but annoying.

Comment: ok, I'll look into that, thanks!